# Fully cover an overflow div with another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

This is a hard one to explain so bear with me (or just skip straight to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhGCn/))

I have a Div with a max-height defined and overlow-x set to scroll. Within this Div there are a bunch of list items (in this instance, addresses). Naturally there can be many of these and they can overflow, which works fine. What I want is a 'cover' div that indicates that this panel is disabled. I have done this by putting an absolutely positioned div within the main div, like so.

```
<div style="max-height:150px;overflow:auto;position:relative">
    <ul>
        <li>Church Walk, Access To Foxholes Farm, DT2 9HG
        </li>
        <li>Garden Cottage, Access To Foxholes Farm, DT2 9HG
        </li>
        <li>Little Bride, Access To Foxholes Farm, DT2 9HG
        </li>
        ...etc
    </ul>
    <div id="overlayDiv" style="display:none;background-color:white;position:absolute;top:0px;opacity:0.8;height:100%;width:100% ">
        <p style="margin-top:50px;text-align:center;font-size:18px;">Searching...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This then appears when the user does something, overlaying the content and making it appear disabled. Great! The problem occurs when my list items overflow. When the overlay div appears it only covers the current visible portion of the parent div, meaning that if I scroll down the div it appears 'uncovered' as the cover div only spans the height of the parent, not including its overflow.

This is really hard to explain so please go to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhGCn/) and click one of the addresses. You'll see that the div gets covered. If you then scroll down that div you will see that the items at the bottom of the list are uncovered.

This also works in reverse so if you click the 'Hide the overlay div' button to get rid of the cover and then click one of the addresses at the bottom of the list, you'll see that the 'cover' still only covers the top part of the div.

Any ideas on how you go about making that cover div extend the entire height of its parent, including the overflow? Other alternative solutions are welcomed and encouraged. Bear in mind that I don't necessarily need the 'Searching' text that gets overlaid on top, just the 'cover' would be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 divs instead of 2 works well:

http://jsfiddle.net/JhGCn/2/

html:

```
<div id="geogPickerAddressResultContainer" style="max-height:150px;overflow:auto;position:relative">
    <div id="insideDiv">
        <ul ...

        </ul>
        <div id="overlayDiv" style="display:none;">
            <p style="margin-top:50px;text-align:center;font-size:18px;">Searching...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#insideDiv {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#overlayDiv {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: That's bang on the money. Cheers for that. Seems like a far too simple solution :)

Answer (score 2):

this works fine too:

http://jsfiddle.net/JhGCn/3/

```
var height = $('#addressPicker li').height();
$.each($('#addressPicker li'), function (i, addr) {
    height += $(this).height();
    $('#overlayDiv').css("height", height + "px");
    etc..
```

Comment: That's clever. I prefer the accepted solution myself but this works nicely too.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the overlay out of the parent, set a z-index and position it over the address picker with negative margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/JhGCn/1/

```
#overlayDiv{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    margin-top:-150px;
    height:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This a pattern I've seen before as well: http://jsfiddle.net/6oa6grn9/

```
#overlayDiv {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```